# Access properties of a class in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Say I have a class in Typescript.

```
class MyAnimal {

   constructor(param1, param2) {
       voice: param1;
       height: param2;
   }
}
```

How do I actually construct the class so that I can access those properties when using the object:

```
var gorilla = new MyAnimal(param1, param2);
```

The above yields a compile error: `Error TS2094: "The property voice does not exist on value of type 'MyAnimal'."`

I converted this over from javascript, where it was working fine, however then it looked like this:

```
var MyAnimal = function (param1, param2) {
    return {
        voice: param1,
        height: param2,
    }
}
```

With that, I could access properties all day

```
var gorilla = MyAnimal(param1, param2);
if (gorilla.height < 5)
    alert("It's a baby gorilla!");
```

I am pretty new to Typescript/javascript, so there's a lot I am still trying to figure out.  I wouldn't think it should be that hard to access properties.  I have a suspicion I am just trying to access it incorrectly.

Am I just building the class wrong?
Why can't I retrieve properties when I new up an instance of `MyAnimal`?

Comment: You're using `propName:` notation outside of an object literal. That creates labels. Try `=` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
constructor(param1, param2) {
   voice: param1;
   height: param2;
}
```

This code simply defines two statement labels called 'voice' and 'height' and does nothing with the parameters. Instead what you want to do is:

```
class MyAnimal {
    voice: string;
    height: number;

   constructor(param1, param2) {
       this.voice = param1;
       this.height = param2;
   }
}
```

You might want to read the [TypeScript Tutorials](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Tutorial/) to get a feel for the basics of the language.

Comment: Thanks all for the quick replies.  As it turns out I just found an
article from `msdn` that gave an example very similar to your answer, so I implemented that format at it seems to be working, thanks!
(insert sheepish smile as I run off to revisit the tutorials)

Comment: This really was the better answer given that it helped the user with the specific syntax problem they were having as opposed to offering up something completely different... even though I like the syntax in my answer better. ;)

Answer (score 2):

This might be the easiest way to fix your code. This automatically creates the public property from the constructor parameters.

```
class MyAnimal {
       constructor(public voice, public height) {
   }
}
```

So now you can do this:

```
var animal = new MyAnimal("rawr", 23);

// use animal.voice
```